# В Android Studio пропали строчки из Quick bug fix Alt+Enter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

В версии `Android 1.2` было так, что если строчка красная - то при нажатии на 
`Quick bug fix (Alt+Enter)` появилоась контекстное окно, где был выбор:

1. `surroind witch try catch`
2. `throws`

Теперь `throws` нету.

**Вопрос:** можно ли вернуть строку `throws`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где Вы это смотрите? Возможно выше просто нельзя пробросить, вот и не предлагает. Создайте отдельный метод для проверки и попробуйте.

Comment: @VAndrJ, Это когда в Android Studio или intellJ IDEA код на Java пишешь и создаешь объект класса. А он использует Exeption. Тогда строчка красным обводиться. При нажатии на Alt+Enter появляется контекстное меню и там раньше 2 строчки были. А теперь только первая строчка.

На картинке 2 строчки. А теперь всегда только Surround try catch. А раньше можно было Throw добавить в метод. Как вернуть их?